# npm run build doesn't work."Opening index.html over file:// won't work."

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use Vue(v2) to build a single page application. Running the command `npm run build` doesn't work; I don't find a static file created in my folder. Although I don't get any error message, I see this in the command line after executing `npm run build`:

> Build complete. Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server. Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

The content of my `build/build.js` file (which is the script that `npm run build` executes) is as follows:

```
require('./check-versions')()
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var ora = require('ora')
var rm = require('rimraf')
var path = require('path')
var chalk = require('chalk')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'))
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

The content of my webpack.prod.conf.js file:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
// Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
// duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
// generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
// you can customize output by editing /index.html
// see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
    // more options:
    // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
  // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
          chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
// keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
// split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
    // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
// extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
// prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
// copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
   var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

What should I do about it?

Comment: is index.html located near package.json in the project root?

Comment: Update your question, what you want to build please mention

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: just give lite-server a try https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server and please tell if it works after installing it globally

Comment: What is your `build` script in package.json actually doing? What command is it running?

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I -  I'm sorry I'm a newbie, I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Young please update your package.json also in the question

Comment: In package.json: `"build": "<command>"` <-- what is your `<command>`?

Comment: @user93 I'm sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- "node build/build.js"

Comment: then what is in build/build.js ??

Comment: require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var ora = require('ora')
var rm = require('rimraf')
var path = require('path')
var chalk = require('chalk')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop()

Comment: if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'))
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})

Comment: Please edit your question and add this code to it. It's too hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Okay, it looks like you are using Webpack. Please add the contents of your `webpack.prod.conf` file to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: I went to config/index.js and changed the `AssetPublicPath` from default path into my own path. And then it worked! But the Tips is still there. I don't think that's a problem anyway.

Comment: what was your path?

Comment: @mikeaxle I’m using my school’s server. So the path was my own folder on the school server.

Answer (score 3):

File: config/index.js
Change assetsPublicPath from '/' to './'

Comment: Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server. what is this error represents? assetsPublicPath problem?